# How to change the text and icon color for android notification

Tags: android

[Notification image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9OXU.jpg)

I want to change the text colors to white, does any knows how to achieve that?

```
notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, RECORDER_CHANNEL)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_recording_progress)
.setPriority(NotificationManagerCompat.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
.setShowWhen(false)
.setContentTitle(title)
.setSubText(getString(R.string.recording_prompt))
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, getString(R.string.notif_pause), pauseBtnPendingIntent)
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_stop, getString(R.string.notif_stop), stopBtnPendingIntent)
.setCustomContentView(mRemoteViewSmall)
.setCustomBigContentView(mRemoteViewBig)
.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.recorderFab))
.setColorized(true)
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
```

Comment: Question needs more explanation. Images from external sources are always difficult because they can be deleted someday. The code does not help to understand the question.